Android Kotlin: Getting Location null when device in Doze mode in OEM devices
I used FusedLocationProviderClient with JobScheduler to get the current location all the time and it works well when the app is in the background.
But the getCurrentLocation() method returns Location = null when I tested with Doze and App Standby command.
I faced this issue in OEM devices like Samsung, Xiaomi, POCO, MOTOROLA, Huawei and so on.
Can anyone help me to solve this?
Here is the code,
LocationJob.kt
class LocationJob : JobService() {

    private var mLocationRequest: LocationRequest? = null
    private var mLocationRequestBuilder: LocationRequest.Builder? = null
    private var mFusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient? = null
    private var mLocationCallback: LocationCallback? = null

    private val workHandler: Handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    var workRunnable: Runnable? = null
    var handlerThread: HandlerThread? = null

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        // TODO: Start a background thread to receive location result.
        handlerThread = HandlerThread("RequestLocation");
        handlerThread!!.start();

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        mLocationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
               //Note: this is not called in case of Doze mode in OEM device.  
                if (locationResult.lastLocation == null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Location missing in callback.")
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Location callback. ${locationResult.lastLocation}")
                }
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult)

            }

            override fun onLocationAvailability(locationAvailability: LocationAvailability) {
                super.onLocationAvailability(locationAvailability)
            }
        }
        if (mLocationRequest == null) {
           if (mLocationRequestBuilder == null){
               mLocationRequestBuilder = LocationRequest.Builder(
                  Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY,
                  sessionManager?.moveOnTripInterval.makeLong()
               )
            }
            mLocationRequestBuilder?.setIntervalMillis()
            mLocationRequestBuilder?.setMinUpdateIntervalMillis()
            mLocationRequest = mLocationRequestBuilder!!.build()
        }
    }

override fun onStartJob(params: JobParameters?): Boolean {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartJob")
        if (mFusedLocationClient != null) return false

        workRunnable = Runnable {
            try {
                mFusedLocationClient!!.requestLocationUpdates(
                    mLocationRequest!!, mLocationCallback!!, handlerThread!!.looper
                )

                Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                    mFusedLocationClient!!.getCurrentLocation(PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, null)
                        .addOnSuccessListener {
                            Log.e("Loc: $it")
                            if (it != null) {
                                val loc = it
                                println("$TAG: ${loc.latitude},${loc.longitude}")
                            } else {
                                Log.e("Loc: is null")
                            }
                        }.addOnFailureListener {
                            println("cancel")
                        }

                }, 10 * 1000)
            } catch (unlikely: SecurityException) {
                println("$TAG Lost location permission. Could not request updates. ")
            }
            jobFinished(params, true)
        }
        workHandler.post(workRunnable!!)
        return true
    }

MainActivity.kt
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      //trigger LocationJob service
        triggerJobService(true)
    }

    fun triggerJobService(start: Boolean) {
        try {
            val jobScheduler =
                getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler
            if (start) {
                val jobInfo =
                    JobInfo.Builder(Constant.JOB_ID, ComponentName(this, LocationJob::class.java))
                        .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
                        .setRequiresDeviceIdle(false).setRequiresCharging(false).setPersisted(true)
//                        .setOverrideDeadline(3 * 60 * 1000)
                val job = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    jobInfo.setMinimumLatency(Constant.REFRESH_INTERVAL)
                        .build()
                } else {
                    jobInfo.setPeriodic(Constant.REFRESH_INTERVAL)
                        .setMinimumLatency(1)
                        .build()
                }
                //.setOverrideDeadline(3 * 60 * 1000)
                jobScheduler.schedule(job)
            } else {
                jobScheduler.cancel(Constant.JOB_ID)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            return
        }
    }

}

I tested in the background also, and all time I got the current location from onLocationResult() of LocationCallback in background but in doze mode this also not working even not getting any callback in doze mode.
RequestManager_FLP com.sec.location.nsflp2 E [LocationManager] Location request 2C7EC95F(Listener) gps interval=0ms (min=0ms) from com.google.android.gms.persistent[WorkSource com....] (10200_FINE_fg_svc_true_foreground) This log message everytime arrived when I put the Samsung device in Doze mode. Can anyone help me on this issue?
This same issue not arrived in fakeGPS and GoogleMap app. Moreover, the UberDriver app and life360 app also work well in doze mode.
